# Same code, Two computers, different functionality?

Tags: php, apache, web, lamp

I'm using Apache, PHP 7.1 (with VSCODE) and Postgres SQL on OSX while my teammate is using APACHE, PHP 7.0, and Postgres SQL also but on Linux.

We both cloned the same repo, and opened up our localhost/website.php

Heres the problem, I have a button

```
<div class="tab">
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openFct(event, 'Add')">Add</button>
</div>
```

that calls some Javascript

```
<script>
function openFct(evt, fct) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks, tabcontent1;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
tabcontent1 = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent1");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent1.length; i++) {
    tabcontent1[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
document.getElementById(fct).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}
</script>
```

which opens up a bar with some tabs on it

```
<div id="Add" class="tabcontent">
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openFct(event, 'AddOwner')">Owner</button>
</div>
```

The problem is, on his computer, when he clicks the ADD tab, it opens up the second tab bar with the word Owner in it, but when I run the same code, no matter how I click the ADD tab, the second tab bar with the word Owner won't appear.

Anybody have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the same browser?

Comment: @ErickStone yes I am, he's using chrome, I've tried chrome, safari, and Firefox

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the developer console? Have you tried setting a breakpoint in that function? Is the function getting called at all? I think you need to narrow the scope of this question a good bit before anyone can help you.

Comment: Also, are the html elements being added properly, but not showing on the page?

Comment: @ErickStone We've tried reinstalling everything on two other computers and came to the conclusion that for some reason, unless we're running linux, our javascript code would not work. With both of us being entirely new to web development, we're not sure why, but we decide to try designing our front end differently. (it's a university project, so not the end of the world)

Comment: Check to make sure the line encodings are the same for both computers.